# Detecting if characters surrounding a given string are evenly matched

Tags: php, regex, string, markdown

I am building a piece of script that has pseudo-markdown in it.

- Wrapping a string in asterisks (*) will make the text bold, by replacing the characters with `<strong>string</strong>`
- Wrapping a string in carats (^) will make the text emphasized, by replacing the characters with `<em>string</em>`

I am using the following regular expression path to evaluate this:

```
$src    = preg_replace('/\*([^*]*)\*/', "<strong>$1</strong>", $inputText);
$in     = preg_replace('/\^([^^]*)\^/', "<em>$1</em>", $src);
$output = rtrim(preg_replace("/(^[\n\n]*|^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $in), "\r\n");
```

This does the following tasks:

- Replaces the asterisks with `<strong>` tags
- Replaces the carats with `<em>` tags
- Strips blank lines, and takes out the trailing newline character

**My Problem**

In my validation, I want to prevent the occurrence of misplaced markdown. If a user enters: `*^this is test^*`, it will work fine. But if they enter (inadvertently) `*^this is test*^`, it will result in HTML `<strong><em>this is test</strong></em>` which of course, is invalid markup.

I want to prevent this in my validation methods, but I am not sure how to parse it in such a way that checks for the appropriately matched pairs. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should make your pattern ungreedy with /U otherwise you run into troubles when two or more **-pairs are in the string

Comment: There's already plenty of markdown libraries out there, why not just use one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed like this:

```
$data = ' markdown. If a user enters: *^this is test^*, it will work fine. But
         if they enter (inadvertently) *^this is test*^, it will';

$pattern = '~([*^])((?>[^^*]+|(?R))+)\1~';

$corr = array('*' => 'strong', '^' => 'em');

do {
    $data = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($corr) {
        return '<' . $corr[$m[1]] . '>' . $m[2] . '</' . $corr[$m[1]] . '>'; 
    }, $data, -1, $count);
} while ($count > 0);

echo htmlspecialchars($data);
```

Note: you can change the last quantifier from `+` to `*` if you want to allow empty strings (i.e. `<em></em>` or `<strong></strong>`).

An other way that uses a stack:

```
$stack = array();
$arr = preg_split('~([*^])~', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

for ($k = 1; $k<count($arr); $k+=2) {
    $lval = end($stack);
    $lkey = key($stack);
    if ($lval == $arr[$k]) {
        $arr[$lkey] = '<' . $corr[$lval] . '>';
        $arr[$k] = '</' . $corr[$lval] . '>';
        array_pop($stack); 
    } else {
        $stack[$k]=$arr[$k];
    }
}

$result = implode('',$arr);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it return false if it encounters invalid markup?

Comment: This script is based on a default behavior, it is not a validation system. Markups are only replaced when the syntaxe is correct. Example with `abc *^defghi*^ jkl^*` will give you `abc *^defghi<strong><em> jkl</em></strong>`. Incorrect markups are skipped. The idea is: since you can't know what the user will write, it is useless to try to correct the string.

Comment: Okay - I was able to use this in creating a validation method. Thank you!

Comment: @BarryChapman: An other way is to write a state machine. it can be interesting to compare the performance of the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent these cases of matching nested tags, change your regex to:

```
$src    = preg_replace('/\*([^^*]*)\*/', "<strong>$1</strong>", $inputText);
$in     = preg_replace('/\^([^^*]*)\^/', "<em>$1</em>", $src);
```

Comment: Ok - that will work for the actual physical action of replacing the characters - however, what would be an appropriate way to simply test the string for validity?

Comment: I'd also suggest to use non-greedy matching/searching

Comment: Something like - if (preg_match(\invalid expression\, 'test string') { return 'error'; }

Comment: To test validity you can use similar regex in: `preg_match('/[*^]([^^*]*)[*^]/', $input);`

Comment: That preg_match expression does not appear to work - it matches both situations

Comment: Ah yes I think both validations need to be separate i.e. `preg_match('/\*([^^*]*)\*/', $input);` and `preg_match('/\^([^^*]*)\^/', $input);`

Comment: That presents a problem, because now it is evaluating two different expressions that may resolve to true independently - but together they are false. I just need to detect occurrences of the mismatched tags.

Comment: If any of those 2 statements return false then it is a fail.